# how to set the amount of items pagination vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

I'm doing an API search and as a result several v-cards are returned, related to each item.

I implemented vuetify pagination, but how to link this and set the number of items per page?

[image: code]

[image: methods]

Comment: You have to create the subsets of items that display on each page yourself listening to the [`@input`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-pagination/#events) event and updating it accordingly.  This [example codepen](https://codepen.io/hyde31456/pen/JjjGpgp) might be of help

Comment: Also please in the future paste your code as snippets in your question instead of just pasting screenshots.  It helps tremendously for others who may want to copy/paste your code as part of their answers.